# Listview onclick issue

Tags: android, listview

I have a problem with the on-click for list view. When I click on the button nothing happens. I have to start a new activty.

I want to know what is wrong with my code:

Imports

```
    public class CountriesListAdapter extends         ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final String[] values;
    ListView listView ;

    public CountriesListAdapter(Context context,      String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.country_list_item, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
 }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View     convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.country_list_item, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewCountryName);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imgViewFlag);

    String g=values[position];
    textView.setText((g).trim());
    if (g.equals("1")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ger);     
    } else if (g.equals("2")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ukra);
    } else if (g.equals("3")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.k);
    } else if (g.equals("4")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.wf);  
    }
    return rowView;}
         protected void onListItemClick(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
             String g=values[position];
                if (g.equals("4")){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Spain.class);
                    context.startActivity(intent);



                }}
 }
```

Comment: where you implement `onListItemClick` ?

Comment: Which button? Did you mean list item?

Comment: i mean on the item of the listview

Comment: @OmarRagab Review my answer .

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    final int position, long id) {

              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Add Your Staff Here
            }
        });
```

You may visit here

> http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/

Comment: For more details you can visit here http://rndp-android.blogspot.in/2014/04/android-listview-onitemclick-event.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the onitemclick listener from the activity or fragment which the listview is added...

for example...

```
 listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.custom_list);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
           //your code to go to the next activity is here...
        }
    });
```

Comment: i want when user click on item 1 start activty 1 for example and if click 2 start activty 2 like this

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized your `values` array correctly. You also didn't add list item click listener, so your click event won't get triggered. Try following code :

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Spain.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```